# Midi implementation within .Net

Tags: c#, midi, sysex

Does anyone have any guidance or recommendations for writing a MIDI-based application in C# Winforms?  I have recently bought a new effects pedal that has a full MIDI implementation (or so I'm led to believe) but the manufacturers have seen fit to not release a librarian / patch editing application.

I have virtually no experience of MIDI beyond plugging a keyboard into another MIDI device, but it can't be that hard, right?  ;-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question and for pushing you above 3000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out this links, this is maybe what you are looking for

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/midiports.aspx

Comment: Thanks for these - I'll check them out when I get home from work!

Answer (score 3):

Also check out [NAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but you can check out my [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) library. It has a lot of [features](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/index.html#features) and rich [documentation](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi). As for working with devices, [this article](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/devices/Overview.html) will be a good start point.