# Turn on a light on the Novation Launchpad and listen for input

Tags: c#, midi

I want to make my own programm for the Novation Launchpad (I'm using the Launchpad MK2).

So I want my C# program to light up a button on the launchpad with the note and the velocity, and I want to run some code when I press a button.

I know it's possible to do that with midi output/input, but I don't know how to send midi output to my Launchpad and listen for midi input.

Comment: So you actually want to know how to do MIDI I/O?

Comment: Yes, but working for a launchpad

Comment: The MIDI API does not work differently; it's the same for all devices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to play MIDI sounds using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763/best-way-to-play-midi-sounds-using-c-sharp), and https://stackoverflow.com/q/333725, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1991159, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1801760.

Comment: It's not the same for all device @CL.
I have the MK2 and the specs are slightly different.